# Array reads, then stops- error: Cannot set property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to read in a csv string to a 2D array and for some reason it stops when it gets to the second iteration of the first loop.

Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hgm8r/) and the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var lay = [[]];

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = value;
 bits = value.split(',');
 console.log(bits.length);
 elm = bits.length/4;
 count=0;
 console.log(bits[6]); //here it reads but won't assign to the array 

 for (i=0; i<=elm; i++)
 {lay[i]=[];
  console.log('i:'+i);
 for (j=0; j<=4; j++)
 {   console.log('j:' + j);
     console.log('count:' + count);;
     lay[i][j] == bits[count];
     count = count + 1;
     console.log('bit value:' + bits[count]);
 }   
 }  
console.log(lay[0][0]);
});
```

The value for the next element reads and displays, but when I try to assign the data to the array it errors out.

## Fixed Code

added the redeclaration of the array in the first loop
That made the error go away.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hgm8r/2/)

Thanks!

Comment: How do you know `lay` or `lay[i]` isn't undefined? I'm actually pretty sure that `lay[1]` is undefined, making `lay[1][0]` fail.

Comment: there's no data in the array, so I guess it is undefined. Why should it matter if I'm telling it what values it should be?

Comment: look at it this way. you wouldn't expect this to work would you? `var x; x[0] = 5;`

Comment: I declared lay=[[]];  isn't that sufficient for the 2D array?  I updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hgm8r/1/  it shows the first few values in the array.  If what you say is true, then why does it display the values of lay[0][0]... lay[0][3]?

Comment: Nope. that only declares lay[0], not lay[1]

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong with u'r lay array I think.
Is this element set? lay[i][j]

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it

http://jsfiddle.net/hgm8r/3/

I've made two changes:

Declared the `lay' value outside the loop

```
var lay = Array();
```

And updated it at the start of the first loop

```
lay[i] = Array();
```

And now it runs without errors.

Comment: I see that by the time that I looked at the code you already solved it. Oh well...